# UITableViewCell subview report wrong height

Tags: swift3, ios10

Before the move to iOS 10, Swift 3, Xcode 8, the following code correctly applies round corners. In the body of tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath):

```
cell.someButton.layer.cornerRadius = floor(cell.someButton.frame.height/2)
```

After the move, the borders disappear and hence no rounded corners for the first few cells. Stepping through using debugger, when the method is called, the subview (someButton) height is wrong. The cell uses layout constraints and is loaded from the storyboard.

Anyone encountered the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have solved it. Here's the resolution if anyone is interested:

Either:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tableView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
        guard let `cell` = cell as? SomeCell else { return }
        cell.someButton.layer.cornerRadius = ceil(cell.someButton.bounds.height/2)
    }
}
```

Or still do the calculation in tableView:willDisplay cell:, just use constants instead of relying on the subview dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

You can add that to your Cell's custom class. Be warned that as of iOS 10 you need to call layoutIfNeeded() to recalculate button size.

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.someButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.someButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.someButton.bounds.size.height / 2
    self.someButton.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add super.awakeFromNib() to the function awakeFromNib(). Like

```
func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.someButton.layer.cornerRadius = floor(self.someButton.frame.height/2)
}
```

Comment: My point is to use  super.awakeFromNib(). In Xcode 8, there shows warning for not calling the super class and i guess in your case that might be the problem. You can set the corner radius to the UITableView delegate method for Cell.

Comment: I am already doing that to customize my cell before posting this question.